# Is there a way to deveop by each module with react, redux, side effect

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I'm developing Web project with react.

But bigger code size the speed is slower. And All code in one system is easy to be complicated and hard to maintain

Is there a way develop by each component with redux, side effect all in one module?

For example, modulizing one component(comtainer) with is's action, stores, side effect. And attach main code with build system..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the day, a single store will contain all state in redux. The exception to this, is if you choose to run two *seperate* apps on the same page - but they wouldn't be linked in any way whatsoever (so ignore it).

However, you can use [combine reducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html) to join reducers from multiple components into one store while keeping them separate. For the majority of apps this will suffice completely, and I would find it hard to imagine it would cause performance issues unless it is set up incorrectly.

Your question doesn't lend itself to one concrete answer, but rather patterns. I would look into "ducks" for redux - its not a technology or library, but rather a pattern for keeping your stores and components modular.

Ducks: https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux

Explanation: https://medium.com/@scbarrus/the-ducks-file-structure-for-redux-d63c41b7035c#.36dsdqd5q

Personal favourite structure doc: https://hashnode.com/post/tips-for-a-better-redux-architecture-lessons-for-enterprise-scale-civrlqhuy0keqc6539boivk2f

If you still feel like redux doesn't align to your modular app, you can consider not using it - sometimes there is no need for it. https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367#.p7j6cioou